# Foreign key from one db context in application user

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Here is the error: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.AspNetUsers_dbo.table_tableId". The conflict occurred in database "master", table "dbo.tables", column 'tableID'.
The statement has been terminated.

I am trying to link a foreign key from a table in my database, but it is part of a different context.

The table that I want to add my foreign key to is ApplicationDbContext, and the foreign key table lives in projectDbContext.

How do I allow these to use each other as foreign keys?

Comment: Maybe a navigation property in the declaration of the dbContext?

Comment: Can't do that - they have to be in the same context. Lots of questions on that out here, but in general you could either combine contexts or do it without a relationship (ie store the key of ApplicationUser and then do a separate lookup when needed).

Comment: Yeah, the second one is what I ended up doing. Thanks for the confirmation!